# gnuplot <lrtb>margin 0 causing unwanted pdf output

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to remove the margin using  `<rltb>margin 0`. However in the created pdf the left and top boarders/axis are visible while the bottom and right are cut out as wanted.

```
unset key
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
plot sin(x)
set output 'sinus.pdf'
set terminal pdf transparent size 4cm,3cm 
set xrange [0:2*pi]
replot
```

Is there a way to fix that? I dont want to just use `unset border` and `unset tics` since I would like the plot to be horizontally/vertically centered (with no border). It seems like `bmargin` and `rmargin` cut off more of the plot than `lmargin` and `tmargin`.

The wrong output looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, setting the terminal to `postscript eps` and converting the eps file to pdf afterward solved the issue. But I still don't understand why the output as pdf causes such a behavior.

Comment: That seems to be a bug. I'll report that later.